# How to clean multiple android project simultaneously?

Tags: android, shell, android-studio, gradle, intellij-idea

System: 4.19.49-1-MANJARO

When making backup of android projects, it's faster to exclude the build folder. I notice 2 way to exclude it :

1. Android Studio -> Build -> Clean Project
2. Delete the folder manually

The problem comes when we have multiple project and all related references(android projects too). It's inconvenience to open project -> clean or delete all folder manually. 
My simple solution is either :

1. Execute clean command on android studio exit
2. Create shell script to check pattern ex. if build.gradle filename exist then delete "build" folder. Then quit from current folder and repeat pattern check for another folder

Question :

1. How to do solution 1 and 2?
2. Are there other convenience way to clean multiple project simultaneously? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For solution 1 and 2, the cleanup action is the same, invoke `gradlew clean` if `gradlew` exists and has executable permission from your Android studio project root. Let gradle to handle the cleanup.

**For solution 1**, you need to create a simple intellij plugin, publish as jar, and install this plugin in Android studio from local by `Install plugin from Disk...`.

The plugin's goal and task is very simple, register some callbacks and just listen the application and project events. On receiving application or project close events, perform your cleanup action.

Because your cleanup is based on project, for solution 1, I suggest you register a project event listener and perform cleanup action on project close callback.

For the implementation of solution 1, it's perfect if you had some background in intellij plugin development. If you don't have, take a look at the [documentation](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/welcome.html) to implement a simple one.

Here is an implementation of solution 1. Create a dummy action, and register listener in the constructor of action.

**plugin.xml**

```
<!-- ... -->
<actions>
<!-- Add your actions here -->
<action id="ExitHooker.DummyAction" class="com.exithooker.DummyAction" text="DummyAction"
        description="This is just a dummy action">
  <add-to-group group-id="ToolsMenu" anchor="last"/>
</action>
```

**DummyAction.java**

```
package com.exithooker;

import com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.AnAction;
import com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.AnActionEvent;
import com.intellij.openapi.application.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.intellij.openapi.application.ApplicationManager;
import com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger;
import com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager;
import com.intellij.openapi.project.Project;
import com.intellij.openapi.project.VetoableProjectManagerListener;
import com.intellij.openapi.project.ex.ProjectManagerEx;
import com.intellij.openapi.vfs.VirtualFile;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class DummyAction extends AnAction {

    public DummyAction() {
        super();
        Logger.getInstance(getClass()).info("DummyAction Loaded");
        ApplicationManager.getApplication().addApplicationListener(new ApplicationAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void applicationExiting() {
                super.applicationExiting();
                Logger.getInstance(DummyAction.this.getClass()).info("applicationExisting");
            }
        });

        ProjectManagerEx.getInstance().addProjectManagerListener(new VetoableProjectManagerListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean canClose(@NotNull Project project) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void projectClosingBeforeSave(@NotNull Project project) {
                Logger.getInstance(DummyAction.class).info("DummyAction.projectClosingBeforeSave");
                final VirtualFile gradlewVirtualFile = project.getBaseDir().findChild("gradlew");
                if (gradlewVirtualFile != null && gradlewVirtualFile.exists() && new File(gradlewVirtualFile.getCanonicalPath()).canExecute()) {
                    Logger.getInstance(DummyAction.class).info(gradlewVirtualFile.getCanonicalPath());

                    ProgressManager.getInstance().runProcessWithProgressSynchronously(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                ProgressManager.getGlobalProgressIndicator().setIndeterminate(true);

                                final int wait = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{
                                        gradlewVirtualFile.getCanonicalPath(), "clean"
                                }, null, new File(gradlewVirtualFile.getCanonicalFile().getParent().getCanonicalPath()))
                                        .waitFor();

                                ProgressManager.getGlobalProgressIndicator().stop();
                                Logger.getInstance(DummyAction.class).info("gradlew clean return = " + wait);
                            } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }, "RUN GRADLEW CLEAN", false, project);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void projectClosed(Project project) {
                Logger.getInstance(DummyAction.class).info("DummyAction.projectClosed");
            }

            @Override
            public void projectClosing(Project project) {
                Logger.getInstance(DummyAction.class).info("DummyAction.projectClosing");
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(AnActionEvent e) {
        Logger.getInstance(getClass()).info("actionPerformed");
    }
}
```

**For solution 2**, the implementation is very simple, just save all your project path, and change to every path to perform `gradlew clean` task in a script.

```
#!/bin/bash
projects=(/path/to/project1 /path/to/project2 /path/to/projectn)
for p in ${projects[@]}
do
    if [ -d $p ];then
        pushd .
        cd $p && [ -x $p/gradlew ] && $p/gradlew clean
        popd
    else
        printf "\e[31merror: $p not exists\e[0m\n"
    fi
done
```

At last, I prefer solution 2 personally. Solution 2 only takes several minutes to write the script, and debug the script is very easy. Solution 1 need to write code, debug plugin and install plugin, and it might take several hours for experienced plugin developer, even several days for beginner.

Comment: Thanks, the script works. :) But I still gonna try to make the plugin since it much more convenience in long run.

Comment: @nfl-x have you finished your plugin?